# How to run a X method 5 times one after another with a time gap of 5sec in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a text view changing for every 5sec for 5 times(Note: I want a sequential call one after another unlike threads ) in  Android.

call x
wait for 5 seconds
call x
wait for 5 seconds 
call x
wait for 5 seconds
call x
wait for 5 seconds 
call x

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    x();
    thread.sleep(5*1000);
}
```

Comment: use CoundownTimer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to do it in Android, you can use Handlers
Try this

```
        private int run = 0;
        private Handler handler=new Handler();
        private Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                xMethod();
// Put your code here, what you want to do 5 times
            }
        };
```

And the method is

```
private void xMethod(){
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        if (run >= 5) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            Log.e("xMethod","handler canceled");
        }
        run++;
        Log.e("xMethod","X Method runs");
    }
```

You just need to put the code in the run method of Runnable and called it from anywhere in the class `xMethod();`

Comment: I have testes this code and its working fine, what issue you are getting?

Comment: just wrote a toast down to xMethod();

Comment: application is running fine but toast is not appering

Comment: sorry forget to call its working thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Hey use Handler and Runnable so that you can call one after another after an fix interval of time.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); //use import android.os.Handler;
private Runnable mRunnable;
private int counter = 0; //To count how many times the method is called
private long timeGap = 1000 * 5; // this is in millisecond means 5 second here

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...existing code

    //call your x method direct in onCreate or in any event listener like below
    mHandler.post(mRunnable);

    //...existing code
}

mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(counter < 5) {// mean max repeated call
            //call your X method (say yourXMethod()) here
            yourXMethod();
            counter++;

            //Now call handler again to call method after timeGap interval of time.
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, timeGap);
            //if you don't want any time gap in between two method call then call like "mHandler.post(mRunnable);"
        } else {
            //delink the runnable with the handler.
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }
    }
};
```

Let me know if it fulfilled your requirement.

Comment: not working bro ....i have just put a toast at yourxmethod();its is not showing me anytoast